# PostgreSQL: Possible to create a function with a TYPE and modify the TYPE after

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Hi I want to create a function which returns a user defined type. After the function is created I want to be able to update the type to something else, so that the function uses the new type eg.

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS ("Column1" text, "Column2" text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_fucntion()
RETURNS SETOF my_type
bla
bla
blah

ALTER TYPE my_type AS ("Name" text, "Address" text)
```

Is this possible? the alterations will always only be the name of the column not the actual data format, that will always be the same.

EDIT: Well the thing is I have 2 scripts one which is generic and must be installed as is with no changes. It has to be installed in multiple places. The second is a sort of config script.

In the generic script I create a function which returns a type of what I wanted to define in the config script.

I thought to install the config script first but I can't as I need to perform some Inserts based on the functions which are in generic script.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried with PostgreSQL 9.1, and it seems to just work.
Example:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type as (col1 text, col2 text);
CREATE TABLE my_table (a my_type);
INSERT INTO my_table values(('ab','cd'));
CREATE FUNCTION my_function() returns setof my_type as 
    'begin return query select (a).* from my_table; end;'
language plpgsql;

select * from my_function();
```

Output is:

```
 col1 | col2 
------+------
 ab   | cd
```

Now let's rename columns in my_type:

```
alter type my_type rename attribute col1 to address;
alter type my_type rename attribute col2 to name;
```

=> No error

Now call again the function:

```
select * from my_function();
```

No error, output is:

```
 address | name 
---------+------
 ab      | cd
```

Looks like the expected result, doesn't it?

Comment: We are using version 9.0 and it seems to not work, doubt they'll be any chance of the sysadmin updating it either, thanks though

Comment: Indeed, it can't work with PG 9.0 for lack of the RENAME ATTRIBUTE clause in ALTER TYPE (according to the doc: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-altertype.html)

Answer (score 1):

Can't see how you could get this to work. Anything depending on "my_type" would break when you changed its definition.

Perhaps post another question with the actual problem you are trying to solve.

EDIT (after question clarification): OK - so you want renamed columns for specific customers or sites or some such. Either wrap your original function in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW local_columns AS
SELECT column1 AS foo, column2 as bar FROM my_function()
```

If you need to pass parameters, wrap your function in another type and function:

```
SELECT * FROM my_outer_function('some','params')
```

Your config file will have to set up the outer type + function or view.

Comment: Edited, but it seems as though I have an endless loop and I don't think it is going to be possible

Comment: I figured something out. I just use this installation process: Install configure script, which creates the types, then in calls the other script, after that's finished then do the inserts

Answer (score 1):

This is generally impossible in PostgreSQL. I quote the manual on [CREATE FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html):

> Also, CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION **will not let you change the return
>   type** of an existing function. To do that, you must **drop and recreate**
>   the function. (When using OUT parameters, that means you cannot change
>   the types of any OUT parameters except by dropping the function.)

Bold emphasis mine. To facilitate the process (and remove the tie between type and function) you might consider using [`OUT` parameters or `RETURNS TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) instead of `RETURNS SETOF my_type`. Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
 RETURNS TABLE (column1 text, column2 text) AS
$BODY$
 -- do something
$BODY$ language xyz;
```

As an aside: My personal advise is to always user [lower case identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in PostgreSQL. I renamed the `OUT` columns accordingly in the example.